# PyErr_SetFromErrno return 0

Tags: python, c

I am trying to extending python with C code. I am trying to raise exception based on the errno value using  [PyErr_SetFromErrno](https://docs.python.org/2/c-api/exceptions.html#c.PyErr_SetFromErrno). This is my code:

```
static PyObject* sum(PyObject* self, PyObject* args) {
   void* c;
   char error[200];

   c = malloc(999999999L * sizeof(int));    
   if(c == NULL) {                  
      strerror_s(error, 200, errno);
      printf("\r\n\r\n ERROR OCCURED! errno value: %d. error string: %s \r\n\r\n", errno, error);
      return PyErr_SetFromErrno(PyExc_BaseException);       
   }

   return NULL;
}
```

The Output:

> ERROR OCCURED! errno value: 12. error string: Not enough space

so the exception I should get from calling my module is:

```
BaseException: (12, 'Not enough space')
```

but instead I am keep getting this exception:

```
BaseException: (0, 'Error')
```

Am I doing something worng?

Comment: What happens if you `PyErr_SetFromErrno` _before_ you call `strerror_s` and `printf`?

Comment: the result is the same.

Comment: How about if you pass a `PyExc_OSError`, rather than BaseException?